# Converting total amount of days in the year so far, to a day in a month

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm converting a timestamp with the payload *1430848842000*, into a `SimpleDateFormat(yyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)`. My output is:

> 2015-05-125 14:00:42

As you can see, the days part of the conversion is odd. Instead of giving me the date in the month of May for this year, it instead gave me the total amount of days in the year leading up to the timestamp creation.

I did some quick math and determined that the 125 time stamp, should really mean the 5th of May, how can I convert this automatically so my output looks like:

> 2015-05-5 14:00:42

?

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: Have you written any code attempting to solve this? Please post it, along with output/errors.

Comment: dd instead of DD http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I think your format string should be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".   See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for the difference between DD and dd.

Answer (score 4):

Your SimpleDateFormat should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` instead of `yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. That is the "*DD*" is "*dd*" instead.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you are using the wrong format to represent the day of the month.

You should use `dd` instead of `DD`.

**mm:** minutes representation

**MM:** representation of the month

**dd:** day representation

**DD:** represents the day of the year (ex: 50 out of 365)

**hh:** the 12 hour clock representation

**HH:** the 24 hour clock representation

### Example:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Date date_now = new Date();

date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss");
date_string = date_format.format(date_now);
System.out.println(date_string);
```

Output:

```
2014-8-07 1:51:12
```